# Csv file manipulation in unix

Tags: csv, sorting, unix, awk, uniq

I have a csv file like this

```
"ID","NAME","TIME"
"858","abc","21:38:52"
"874","ghi","18:20:33"
"858","abc","19:38:52"
"978","def","21:38:52"
"874","ghi","13:20:33"
"319","ghi","13:24:50"
"319","ghi","22:29:16"
```

Some records are the same except they differ in time (represented in the third column), and basically I want only the latest records. I need a command to identify the duplicate records and delete those with older timestamps so my output file looks like this:

```
"ID","NAME","TIME"
"858","abc","21:38:52"
"978","def","21:38:52"
"874","ghi","18:20:33"
"319","ghi","22:29:16"
```

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: My suggestion is to go with python and csv module

Comment: @Inian Iam not well versed in unix.. so need help

Comment: @DDS Is there any one liner to do this

Comment: @John I don't think, I think little code is required

Comment: Do you **really** want to delete the one with the oldest timestamp or do you actually want to only print the one with the youngest timestamp? They're different requirements when you have 3 or more duplicate keys. Is your input always sorted by timestamp for each key value?

Comment: @EdMorton My input is not sorted. If there are two or more records with identical entries except for timestamps, i need only one with the youngest timestamp along with other records in the file whose timestamps also have to be the latest.

Comment: OK then post a new question with truly representative sample input and expected output if you need help (or deselect the accepted answer so you'll get others and update this question instead of asking a new one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following `awk`.

```
awk -F"," '!b[$1,$2]++{c[++count]=$1 OFS $2} {a[$1,$2]=$0} END{for(i=1;i<=count;i++){print a[c[i]]}}' SUBSEP=" " Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -F"," '
!b[$1,$2]++           {  c[++count]=$1 OFS $2  }
                      {  a[$1,$2]=$0           }
END{
 for(i=1;i<=count;i++){ print a[c[i]]          }
}
' SUBSEP=" "  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk -F"," '
!b[$1,$2]++           {  c[++count]=$1 OFS $2  } ##Checking if array b whose index is $1,$2 value is NOT more than 1 if yes then create array c whose index is variable count(whose value is getting incremented each time cursor comes here) and its value is $1 OFS $2.
                      {  a[$1,$2]=$0           } ##Then creating an array named a whose index is $1,$2(first and second field of current line) and value is current line value.
END{                                             ##Starting END block of awk here.
 for(i=1;i<=count;i++){ print a[c[i]]          } ##Starting a for loop whose values starts from i=1 to till count value and printing array a value whose index is array c value, where array c index is variable i.
}
' SUBSEP=" " Input_file                          ##Setting SUBSEP as space for array and mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: The approach is great, but you're depending on `OFS` to be `" "` in order to match your modified `SUBSEP`. Why not just do `c[++count]=$1 SUBSEP $2` and not have to worry about keeping them in sync?  And then you'll also have no need to modify `SUBSEP` from its original value, which is designed to be a better alternative to `" "`   (_The default value of SUBSEP is the string "\034", which contains a nonprinting character that is unlikely to appear in an awk program or in most input data._)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i need some more explanations like in which part does the comparison happen between two records

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 sorry... I have edited my question now

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i am not able to delete this question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172088/discussion-between-john-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 
Im sorry i did not know what i was doing i am new here.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ tac file | awk -F, '!seen[$1]++' | tac
"ID","NAME","TIME"
"858","abc","21:38:52"
"978","def","21:38:52"
"874","ghi","13:20:33"
"319","ghi","22:29:16"
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: You are wrong. Trivial solutions that anyone can figure out with a brief glance at google an/d/or a man page are best left as-is since people learn a lot more from doing that than just how one script works.

Answer (score 0):

Several answers thus far have implicitly relied on timestamps already being ordered/sorted in the file.  The following makes no such assumption:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { FS = OFS = SUBSEP = "," }
FNR == 1 {
    split("", tt) # Time Text
    split("", ts) # Numeric Timestamp
    print
    next
}
{
    t = $3
    gsub(/[":]/, "", t)
    if ((($1, $2) in ts) && (ts[$1, $2] >= t))
        next
    ts[$1, $2] = t
    tt[$1, $2] = $3
}
END {
    for (x in tt)
        print x, tt[x]
}
```

Comment: you could probably simplify it like `awk -F, 'NR>1 && (!a[$1 OFS $2] || a[$1 OFS $2] < $3) { a[$1 OFS $2]=$3 } END { for (i in a) print i, a[i] }' OFS=,`

Comment: You are right that the indexing can be combined...  (Um, don’t you need -v for the OFS?). I think I would still check with “in” for empty, because a blank cell does not return 0, but “”.  For the test for inequality, I don’t know if it will work as a string comparison, but may only do numeric compare of the first colon delimited number... I will look it up.  Thank you very much for your comment @Subbeh

Comment: `$ awk 'BEGIN { print 1, 2 }' OFS=:` -> 1 2
`$ awk 'BEGIN { print 1, 2 }' -v OFS=:` -> 1 2
`$ awk -v OFS=: 'BEGIN { print 1, 2 }'` -> 1:2

Comment: `$ echo b | awk '!a[1] { print "happy" }'` -> happy

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN { print ("1:00:00" < "10:00:00") ? "good" : "bad" }' `-> bad `awk 'BEGIN { print ("10000" < "100000") ? "good" : "bad" }'` -> good `awk 'BEGIN { print ("018000" < "100000") ? "good" : "bad" }'` -> good -- because the last one is good, it makes sense to not use separate h,m,s arrays for timestamp.

Comment: OFS can be used at the end if working with input: `echo 3 4 | awk 'BEGIN { print 1, 2 } { print $1, $2 }' OFS=,` ->
1 2
3,4

Comment: you're right about comparing the strings, but since we're working with timestamps and assuming they have a fixed length, it works: `awk 'BEGIN { print ("01:00:00" < "10:00:00") ? "good" : "bad" }'` -> good